# Access control -- protected members from outside the package

Tags: java, access-control

i've got the class `P4` in the default package (i know using the default package is bad practice, but merely "for example" for now):

```
import temp.P2;

public class P4 extends P2 {

public void someMethod() {    
    P2 p2 = new P2();
//        p2.p2default();   // ERROR as expected
    p2.p2public();
    p2.p2protected();  // ERROR as not expected
}    

}
```

and class `P2` in package `temp`

```
package temp;

public class P2 {

protected void p2protected() {    
...
}    

public void p2public() {    
...
}    

void p2default() {    
...
}    

}
```

From the [access control mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), i'd expect 
`P4`-- having extended `P2`, should be able to see the `protected` member of its super class even from outside the package once it imported the namespace of that package.

What am i missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `P2 p2 = new P2();` of type `P2` and *not* `P4`. If `p2` were of type `P4` it would have access to it since it is a subclass of `P2`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue may be that you are not trying to *inherit* the `p2protected()` method, which you should be able to do, but rather to *call* `p2protected()`. You cannot call a `protected` method on a different object from a different package, even if you are extending the class. `super.p2protected()` should work, however.

Comment: thx - yours & @manouti's explain all&well. his is more direct. you get the upvote & he the accept.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.6.2) :

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared **only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object**.

In your code you are trying to access the protected member of another object.

```
public void someMethod() {    
    P2 p2 = new P2();

    p2.p2protected();  // doesn't work, because someMethod and p2.p2protected
                       // operate on different objects (this vs. p2) 

    p2protected (); // works, because someMethod and p2protected operate
                    // on the same object (this)
}
```